# Querying dm_db_index_usage_stats returns empty row

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a user telling me that some data in our app has changed.

Using [this example](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/05/09/sql-server-find-last-date-time-updated-for-any-table/), I ran the following query on the table that populates the data in the app:

```
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(OBJECT_ID) AS TableName,
 last_user_update,*
FROM sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats
WHERE database_id = DB_ID( 'Mydatabase')
AND OBJECT_ID=OBJECT_ID('mytable')
```

I don't get any rows back, so it seems there's no history of the data in the table as having been updated?

I ran

```
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(OBJECT_ID) AS TableName,
 last_user_update,*
FROM sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats
WHERE database_id = DB_ID( 'Mydatabase')
```

and I got back 13 rows, several of them had null for the TableName though.

Comment: Do you get back an object_id?  Is it possible that object_id maps to an object in another database or another server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first point:

> The counters are initialized to empty whenever the SQL Server
>   (MSSQLSERVER) service is started. In addition, whenever a database is
>   detached or is shut down (for example, because AUTO_CLOSE is set to
>   ON), all rows associated with the database are removed.

So if your server was restarted or something you don't have statistics.

The second point:

Use `database_id` parameter when you call `OBJECT_NAME` function:

```
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(OBJECT_ID, DB_ID( 'Mydatabase')) AS TableName,
 last_user_update,*
FROM sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats
WHERE database_id = DB_ID( 'Mydatabase')
```